# Are there any benefits to using different Racial Appearance Motif's when crafting?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

What are the benefits to racial motifs other than the appearance of the crafted item, if any? Do they offer different stats or bonuses?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The effects of the racial motifs are entirely cosmetic; the statistics of a given item will be identical no matter the style used in crafting it.

The only near-edge case where style can have an impact is in the 'Convert to Imperial' option given to players who purchased the Imperial Edition of the game; this allows such players to convert items in any style to Imperial style, but also immediately makes the item bound so they cannot trade it. This is, however, more a side effect of the conversion than the style; the stats on the item remain what they were, and this doesn't affect items crafted directly in Imperial style, only items converted to it this way.